# Prolog query with default for missing values

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

Say I have the following database in Prolog.

```
person(fred).
person(bob).
person(alice).

alias(fred,"Frederick the Great").
alias(bob,"Spongey").
```

Now I want to be able to search for aliases but get the original name back as a default when there is no alias available.

Eg. to get

```
fred, "Frederick the Great"
bob, "Spongey"
alice, alice
```

back

My first try was to add another clause for the alias predicate.

```
alias(X,X).
```

But this gives me

```
fred,"Frederick the Great"
fred, fred
bob, "Spongey"
bob, bob
alice, alice
```

But I don't want the non-alias version when there is an alias available.

How would I do this in Prolog?

Answer (score 2):

OK.

I worked it out :

```
person(fred).
person(bob).
person(alice).

alias(fred,"Frederick the Great").
alias(bob,"Spongey").

name(X,Y) :- 
  alias(X,Y). 

name(X,X) :-
  person(X),
  not(alias(X,_)).
```

Comment: You should be using `\+ alias(X, _)` instead of `not(alias(X,_)).`

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: `\+` is the portable, ISO predicate. `not/1` is an older, non-standard predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional for this without defining additional rules or using `not` or `\+`:

```
?- person(X),
   (   alias(X, Y)
   *-> true
   ;   X = Y
   ).
X = fred,
Y = "Frederick the Great" ;
X = bob,
Y = "Spongey" ;
X = Y, Y = alice.
```